# Hazelcast Jet 0.6.1 DAG vs PipeLine API

Tags: hazelcast-jet

I have created the following sample code  for DAG to understand the aggregation. It seems, the `slidingWindow` vertex does not emit any records.

Not sure, what's going wrong here..

```java
public DAG buildDAG() {
    DAG dag = new DAG();
    SlidingWindowPolicy winPolicy = slidingWinPolicy(SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH_MILLIS, SLIDE_STEP_MILLIS);

     Vertex source = dag.newVertex("source", SourceProcessors.streamRemoteMapP(getRemoteSourceName(),
              getClientConfig(), START_FROM_OLDEST,  WatermarkGenerationParams.noWatermarks()));


    Vertex slidingWindow = dag.newVertex("aggregate-to-sliding-win",
          aggregateToSlidingWindowP(
                  singletonList((v) ->  getUserID((Entry<String, CacheEntry<Record>>)v)),
                  singletonList((v) ->  getTimeStamp((Entry<String, CacheEntry<Record>>)v)),
                  TimestampKind.EVENT,
                  winPolicy,
                  counting(),
                  TimestampedEntry::new));


    Vertex peekOP = dag.newVertex("peekOP", DiagnosticProcessors.writeLoggerP());
    Vertex peekOP1 = dag.newVertex("peekOP1", DiagnosticProcessors.writeLoggerP());

    Vertex sink = dag.newVertex("sink", SinkProcessors.writeFileP("c:\\\\data\\\\op1.txt"));

  return dag
          .edge(between(source, peekOP))
          .edge(between(peekOP, slidingWindow))
          .edge(between(slidingWindow,peekOP1))
          .edge(between(peekOP1, sink));
}
```

Similarly, I created the following sample code for Pipeline API for aggregation.

This works well. This prints the records in the text file.

```java
private Pipeline buildPipeline() {

    Pipeline p = Pipeline.create();

    p.drawFrom(Sources.<String, CacheEntry<AuditLogRecord>>remoteMapJournal("cache_AuditLog", getClientConfig(), START_FROM_OLDEST))
      .addTimestamps((v) ->  getTimeStamp(v), 3000)
      .peek()
    .groupingKey((v) -> Tuple2.tuple2(getUserID(v),getTranType(v)))
    .window(WindowDefinition.sliding(SLIDING_WINDOW_LENGTH_MILLIS, SLIDE_STEP_MILLIS))
    .aggregate(counting())
    .map((v)-> getMapKey(v))
    .drainTo(Sinks.files("c:\\data\\op.txt"));
    return p;
  }
```

Will you please help me to correct the DAG definition?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems:

1. WatermarkGenerationParams.noWatermarks(): to have any output for windowing processors, you need watermarks. Use `wmGenParams((v) ->  getTimeStamp(v), limitingLag(3000), emitByFrame(winPolicy), -1)`
2. the `DiagnosticProcessors.writeLoggerP()` is a sink. It receives items but doesn't emit any. To peek at a vertex, wrap the processor supplier in `peekInputP( /* original supplier */ )` or `peekOutputP`
3. the edge to `slidingWindow` must be `distributed` and `partitioned`. Without these you'll get results, but incorrect ones.

The DAG API is intended for advanced use cases which are not possible using the Pipeline API. With each Jet release the need to use DAG API diminishes. As your samples show, the Pipeline API is easier to write and more concise.